# What am i doing wrong with my C# looping

Tags: c#

Ok so i have 2 lists

```
List<string> playlists 
List<string> sync
```

and the lets say the content of playlists is three strings

```
{"more and you", "and us", "more"}
```

and the content of sync is this

```
{"more and you-20120312", "more and you-20120314", "more and you-20120313",  "and us-20120313",  "and us-20120314",  "more-20120314",  "more-20120313", "more-20120312"}
```

Basically what i want to do is loop through all the loop through the playlists and find the associated syncs and print them out and they need to be 3 otherwise i want to color them differently..So here is my code so far

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<h2>Playlist Information</h2>");
        foreach (string play in playlists)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (string s in sync)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith(play))
                {
                    sb.Append("<p class=\"good\">" + s + "</p>");
                    counter++;
                } 
            }
        }
```

So i want the final html to look like this

```
<h2>Playlist Information</h2>
<p class=\"good\">more and you-20120312</p>
<p class=\"good\">more and you-20120313</p>
<p class=\"good\">more and you-20120314</p>
<p class=\"bad\">and us-20120313</p>
<p class=\"bad\">and us-20120314</p>
<p class=\"good\">more-20120312</p>
<p class=\"good\">more-20120313</p>
<p class=\"good\">more-20120314</p>
```

the bad for the items that dont meet at least 3...any ideas on how to achieve this with my code

Comment: The output seems not to match what the code would write: there is no output of 'bad' class in the code provided.

Comment: yes i have not written that yet because i didnt know how to check for the count of items or exactly 3...thats what my question is about..to help me finish my snippet

Comment: @SergeySirotkin he's saying that he got this far and doesn't know how to continue from here.  He know's it's not working.

Comment: It seems you just need to add the dash into the string used in the starts with compare. Otherwise you are getting the items that start with more in both the "more and you" loop and the "more" loop.

Comment: How are each of these lists generated?  You probably want to store the data in a different manor that's more compatible with the algorithm you need to run.

Comment: they are generated my searching for files and list.add as i find them

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to achieve this - just build another list during your check instead of the counter and then check the size of the "innerlist". I called it currentSyncSet:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>(){"more and you", "and us", "more"};
        List<string> sync = new List<string>() { "more and you-20120312", "more and you-20120314", "more and you-20120313", "and us-20120313", "and us-20120314", "more-20120314", "more-20120313", "more-20120312" };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<h2>Playlist Information</h2>\r\n");

        HashSet<string> finalSyncResult = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (string play in playlists)
        {
            List<string> currentSyncSet = new List<string>();

            foreach (string s in sync)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith(play))
                {
                    currentSyncSet.Add(s);
                }
            }

            foreach (var syncset in currentSyncSet)
            {
                if (currentSyncSet.Count < 3)
                {
                    finalSyncResult.Add("<p class=\"bad\">" + syncset + "</p>");
                }
                else
                {
                    finalSyncResult.Add("<p class=\"good\">" + syncset + "</p>");
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var result in finalSyncResult)
        {
            sb.Append(result + "\r\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The Output is then:

```
<h2>Playlist Information</h2>
<p class="good">more and you-20120312</p>
<p class="good">more and you-20120314</p>
<p class="good">more and you-20120313</p>
<p class="bad">and us-20120313</p>
<p class="bad">and us-20120314</p>
<p class="good">more-20120314</p>
<p class="good">more-20120313</p>
<p class="good">more-20120312</p>
```

Greetings

**Update 1:**
Sry, last time, i forgot, that you don't want to have duplicate entries - therefore i added a HashSet in this solution.